# Not receiving confirmation mail with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise, sendgrid

Following a tutorial where I am adding user authentication to a basic rails app.

There is a step where I have to add the following code to a `setup_mail.rb` file

```
if Rails.env.development?
  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    address:        'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    port:           '587',
    authentication: :plain,
    user_name:      ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    password:       ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    domain:         'heroku.com',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
end
```

I have added the sendgrid addon, and put user id and password on the application.yml file as well.

But when I sign up, I do not receive a confirmation mail.

cross checked the `development.rb` file as well and made sure the following code was present

```
....
   config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }
   config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
   config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
end
```

Followed the tutorial word to word. Hence really stumped! Google pointed me to a few places and confused me futher!

This is how my migration db file looks like at the moment

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Customization
       t.string :name
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
       t.string   :confirmation_token
       t.datetime :confirmed_at
       t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
       t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is    :failed_attempts
  # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
  # t.datetime :locked_at


  t.timestamps
end

add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
# add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
# add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

Here is my user.rb file as well

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
end
```

These are the steps I followed in order

1. Installed devise gem, ran `bundle`
2. `rails g devise:install`
3. Added the above code to development.rb file
4. `rails g devise:views`
5. `rails g devise User`
6. Uncommented `confirmable` in the migration file`
7. `rake db:migrate`
8. Added `:confirmable` to the User class in user.rb
9. `heroku addons:add sendgrid:starter`
10. `heroku congif:get SENDGRID_USERNAME`
11. `heroku config:get SENDGRID_PASSWORD`
12. Created config/initializers/setup_mail.rb and added the above mail settings.
13. Installed figaro.
14. Added environment variables to application.yml file
15. `figaro heroku:set -e production

Update

Added mail settings in development.rb as well, no luck.

Tried changing the domain from `domain: 'heroku.com'` to `domain: 'sendgrid.com'`, no luck.

Here is the server log. It appears that the mail has been sent but I cannot find it in the inbox or spam

```
Sent mail to myemail@gmail.com (2070.9ms)                                                                                                                                                    
Date: Wed, 07 Jan 2015 13:52:05 +0000                                                                                                                                                             
From: please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com                                                                                                                                  
Reply-To: please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com                                                                                                                              
To: myemailgmail.com                                                                                                                                                                        
Message-ID: <54ad3a05d2b29_1ba3fb59082841433253@bloc-ruby-179559.mail>                                                                                                                            
Subject: Confirmation instructions                                                                                                                                                                
Mime-Version: 1.0                                                                                                                                                                                 
Content-Type: text/html;                                                                                                                                                                          
 charset=UTF-8                                                                                                                                                                                    
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit                                                                                                                                                                   

 <p>Welcome !</p>                                                                                                                                                            

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>                                                                                                                                 

 <p><a href="http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation? confirmation_token=W3xuYfA8aq2obMBmffghfghQaDt">Confirm my account</a></p>                                                                          

   (45.0ms)  commit transaction                                                                                                                                                                   
Redirected to http://bloc-ruby-179559.apse1.nitrousbox.com/                                                                                                                                       
Completed 302 Found in 2872ms (ActiveRecord: 46.4ms)
```

Comment: Show me your User class...!!!

Comment: Updated question with user class

Comment: set up your mail setting in config/environments/development.rb then restart your rails server

Comment: Tried it, didn't work.

Comment: which mail service you are using!!!

Comment: I've outlined the entire set of steps I took in the question. Maybe I did something wrong there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check to make sure Sendgrid doesn't have your account on hold. Log in through your Heroku dashboard. Then click on your app. Then under addons, click on Sendgrid. This will take you to their dashboard. If there is a warning saying that your account is on hold pending review, you'll have to contact them and have them remove it.

Answer (score 2):

You are running it for development mode. Mails are formed and can be seen in logs but not delivered. They will not be sent in dev mode by default.To enable, use this in development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

use the below code in config/environments/development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => "sendgrid.com",   
    :user_name            => ""
    :password             => ""
    :authentication       => 'plain',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. But I have already entered that line of code in the development.rb file as you can see in my question.

Answer (score 0):

In mail_setup.rb, try changing the first line to:

```
if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.production?
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with `:confirmable`. I was not able to get the email to send, but I was able to trick the app into thinking that it had been sent and confirmed - and therefore login.

[:confirmable info](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable)

In the console:

```
User.find(1).confirm       # returns true unless it's already confirmed
User.find(1).confirmed?    # true/false
User.find(1).send_confirmation_instructions # manually send instructions
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was using my gmail account with localhost environment, when i check my mail, i show a mail from google saying "Sign-in attempt was blocked" due to "Less secure app blocked" , you can enable it need to follow instruction as received in    [mail link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?authuser=1)

Answer (score 0):

In development setup, by default mails are not sent

we can enable by setting
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

if it is still not solved ,we can set

config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

and we can find the exact issue printed in console