# Devise emails are not being sent using sendgrid while other emails are being sent well

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, devise, sendgrid

I am using sendgrid to send emails in production my all other emails are being sent as expected but all the devise emails are not being sent neither a crash occur my in my production.rb I have

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'myapp.herokuapp.com' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    port: 587,
    domain: 'heroku.com',
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: ENV["SENDGRID_USERNAME"],
    password: ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"]
  }
```

Why my other emails are being sent except devise emails via sendgrid and how can I be able to send devise emails using sendgrid?

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27815873/not-receiving-confirmation-mail-with-devise

Comment: Thanks @Pavan but as I said my other notifications/emails are being send properly via sendgrid

Comment: Is this happening locally, in production or both?

Comment: @MartynDavies only in production for development I'm not using sendgrid

Comment: @AsnadAtta If you switch raise_delivery_errors to true, do you get anything at all?

Comment: @MartynDavies it helped I resolve the issue please answer it I will mark as accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you switch `config.raise_delivery_errors` to `true` then you'll be able to see if there's a specific problem and work backwards from there.